# How to change where an email is sent FROM in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email

I found this VBA code for Excel which automatically sends an email using Column A as address to be sent to, Column B is any CC addresses, Column C is the body of the email, Column D is the filepath of an attachment.

I don't need Column B to include CC however I need the email to be sent from a specific email address shared with colleagues.  (not my default personal which it currently does)

This code wasn't written by myself so any help would be great!

[Here is how the Excel SS looks so far with currently 2 examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQp5w.png)

Below is the VBA code I currently have and it works perfectly so far:

```
Sub Send_Files()


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Enter the path/file names in the D:Z column in each row
    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("D1:Z1")
    
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        With OutMail
            .to = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value
            .cc = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value
            .Subject = "Example Subject 1"
            .Body = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 3).Value
            
            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell
            
            .Send 'Or use .Display/Send
        End With
        
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

I currently haven't tried anything as I didn't write the code itself and my VBA knowledge is very limited!

Comment: Do you understand what the lines `.cc = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value` and `.Subject = "Example Subject 1"` are doing? That should be a good starting point

Comment: @BigBen Hi, I am incredibly blind, I didn't even see the .Subject line... this let me change the subject just as I wanted, thank you lol! I just need a way to change the address the emails get sent from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the 'with outmail', insert this line:

```
      .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email_address@domain.com"
```

So it should look like this after you made the changes, just replace the "email_address@domain.com" with the email address you want to use.

```
      With OutMail
         .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email_address@domain.com"
         .to = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value
         .cc = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value
         .Subject = "Example Subject 1"
         .Body = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 3).Value
```